# Calculating energy difference between two 1-4 dimethylcyclohexane conformers

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, conformers, cyclohexane

The following question was asked in a quiz at my college

> Draw the most stable and least stable chair conformer for 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane and calculate the
> energy difference between these two. Given that the value for CH3-H diaxial interaction = 3.8 kJ/mol and
> CH3-CH3 gauche interaction = 3.8 kJ/mol. Ignore the gauche interaction with the ring C atoms

I drew the Newman projection but I am unable to understand how to proceed further as to which CH3-H pairs to consider and which not to, also in the Newman projection will the two methyl even interact?

Comment: [Look here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#Conformation).

Comment: A second thought. Conformational structures and/or molecular models are better than Newman projections for what you are trying to accomplish.